# How do I post on my facebook wall via my facebook ID?

Tags: facebook

I used below code to post on my facebook wall using php.

```
    include_once("libs/social-sdk/facebook/facebook.php");
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'my_app_id',
        'secret' => 'my_secret'
    ));
    try {
        $publishStream = $facebook->api("/my_profile_id/feed", 'post', array(
            'message' => "I love thinkdiff.net for facebook app development tutorials. :)",
            'link' => 'http://example.com',
            'picture' => 'http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/mad-programmer-17296778.jpg',
            'name' => 'Test Post',
            'description' => 'This is my first post using php :)'
                )
        );
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($e); echo "</pre>";
    }
```

But It throw me an exception error:

> **(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action**
>
> I used **scope: 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday'** during login

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

`publish_stream` is deprecated since years, you need `publish_actions` and you need to authorize a User before you can use it to post: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Also, you should use `/me/feed` for posting, because you can´t post on the wall of another user than the authorized one anyway.

You may want to read the platform policy too: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

> 2.3: Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

And then you need to read the Review Guidelines, because publish_actions and user_birthday need to get approved by Facebook before they will work for other users (without a role in your App): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login